# add custom method on redirect() helper in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add custom method on redirect() helper such as it:

```
redirect()->custom(...$params)
```

Do it posibble?

Comment: Have a look at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#response-macros

Comment: `Illuminate\Routing\Redirector`, what is returned from `redirect()`, is macroable itself

Comment: @lagbox can you explain more ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can macro a custom method on the `Redirector` class if you would like. In a Service Provider's `boot` method you can define your macro:

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Redirector;

public function boot()
{
    Redirector::macro('custom', function ($your, $arguments, $here) {
        ...
    });
}
```

Then you could access it the way you would like:

```
redirect()->custom(...);
```

The `Redirector` has been macroable since version 5.5.